# How to perform regression with different error variances?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references, weighted-regression

I have two series of measurements values, first series is X and second is Y.
I need to model Y as a function of X, where I know the method that was used to measure X is two times better then the method used for measure Y in terms of error variance.

I red about regression with error term in the independent variable, but I'm not sure what to do when there is also error term in the dependent variable and they are different.

Which technique/tools/constraints should I use for this sort of case?